# Generalized linear algebraic equation solver

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

$\newcommand{\d}{\vec{d}}$
$\newcommand{\S}{\vec{S}}$

In Mathematica one can easily solve a linear system given by 
$$A \vec{S} = \vec{d}$$
where $A$ is a matrix, simply by using 
`S = LinearSolve[A,d]`.

I don't know if this has a name, but I am wondering if there is a nice way to solve a generalized system of linear equations such as this one (this is a specific example but the form of the matrix on the left is unimportant, only that it is a "matrix of matrices"):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & A & 0 &   &   & 0           \\[8pt]
-A & 1 & A &   &   &            \\[1pt]
0 & -A & 1 & \ddots &   &       \\[1pt]
  &   & \ddots & \ddots &   &   \\[1pt]
  &   &   &   & 1 & A           \\[6pt]
0 &   &   &   & -A & 1      
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\S_1     \\[3pt]
\S_2     \\[3pt]
\S_3     \\[3pt]
\vdots   \\[3pt]
\S_{N-1} \\[3pt]
\S_{N}   
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\d_1     \\[3pt]
\d_2     \\[3pt]
\d_3     \\[3pt]
\vdots   \\[3pt]
\d_{N-1} \\[3pt]
\d_{N} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $1$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. The $\S_i$ and $\d_i$ are $n$-component vectors, the $\d_i$ are known and I want to solve for the $\S_i$.

The "brute force" way to solve this is to `Flatten` the "vectors of vectors" and `ArrayFlatten` the "matrix of matrices", then use `LinearSolve`, then use `Partition[S,n]` to recover the vectors. But I feel like such systems must not be that uncommon and maybe there is some built in method of doing this.

Comment: By the way, this does not look like Crank-Nicolson. Crank-Nicolson is for transient PDEs but your system looks more like stemming from an elliptic boundary value problem.

Comment: More detail on my problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801044/crank-nicolson-for-coupled-pdes

Comment: I am simply following an assignment which says to solve using Crank-Nicolson, I believe that my code is working, the results do seem reasonable. I applied boundary conditions that $\rho$ and $v$ are zero at the edges.

Comment: Some actual code would be useful here. Otherwise it becomes a do-my-homework type of question, better suited for math.SE perhaps.

Comment: I already solved the problem using a method somewhat similar to the one below. My question is asking if such a generalized linear algebra problem can be solved in Mathematica without using `Flatten` and `Partition`. It would be nice to have an option for such a problem built in to `LinearSolve` for example.

Comment: I can add some code later, but in the meantime I made the question less specific to what I'm working on and more general.

Comment: I believe the question was improved and that an answer might be of general interest. I retracted my close vote and you got me re-open vote.

Comment: Still, an example `A` and code to construct the system would probably encourage people to try to answer. (You mention `Flatten`, but have you seen `ArrayFlatten`?)

Answer (score 8):

You can build the system matrix as follows

```
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}];
A = A\[Transpose].A;
n = 10;
AA = Plus[
  KroneckerProduct[SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> -1, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}, {n, n}], A],
  KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray], N@IdentityMatrix[2]]
  ]
```

The right-hand side can be assembled as follows:

```
d = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
S1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2}];
Sn = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2}];
b = Flatten[d];
b[[;; 2]] += A.S1;
b[[-2 ;;]] -= A.Sn;
```

Solve as usual (this is a usual linear system). I'd suggest a solver specialized for banded matrices:

```
x = LinearSolve[AA, b, Method -> "Banded"];
```

In order to convert back to a list of pairs, you can use

```
Partition[x,2]
```

Comment: Thanks, while this does solve the problem (I wrote a similar code) I was hoping there might be a built in way to handle such problems.

Comment: More general block matrices can be converted to a a single large matrix with `ArrayFlatten`. In the end, such a task has to be done since `LinearSolve` uses external libraries which expect a matrix as input.

Comment: Aha I have not really used `ArrayFlatten`, but that makes the problem relatively trivial to do then. Just `Flatten`/`ArrayFlatten` everything, use `LinearSolve`, then `Partition`. Okay that's not too bad, especially since the matrix doesn't need to be partitioned again. I wonder if such a problem has a name, I can't imagine this is uncommon.

Comment: Sorry for the hassle but I changed the question to make it more general, so parts of your answer don't exactly make sense now in the context of the question, if you have the time to update it.